# Modal Logic Proof in System T

Tags: logic, modal-logic, proof

I need to provide an axiomatic proof of the following formula in System T of modal logic: ◇(A→□B)→(□A→◇B). Any advice on how to start would be great!

Answer (score 0):

To some extent, producing any proof depends on what rules you are allowed to use. Here is a sketch of a proof that you may be able to use as a basis.

```
1. ◇(A → □B)                    Assumption
2. □A                           Assumption
3. ◇(¬A V □B)                   1, Impl. 
4. ◇¬A V ◇□B                    3, ◇-disjunction
5. ¬◇¬A                         2, defn of ◇
6. ◇□B                          4,5, Hyp. Syll.
7. ◇B                           6, T 
8. □A → ◇B                      2,7, CP
9. ◇(A → □B) → (□A → ◇B)        1,8, CP
```